# Integral with exponential (or K-Bessel function) depending on a parameter equal to zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, exponential-function, bessel-functions

Can we find $a$ complex such that:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-c} e^{-a x^2} dx =0$$

($c$ is complex with $1>Re(c)>0$)

Same question with this other integral, can we find a complex $\alpha$ such that ($K_{\alpha}(x)$ is the K-Bessel function):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-\frac{1}{2}} K_c (\alpha x) dx =0$$

($c$ is also fixed complex with $\frac{1}{2}>Re(c)>0$)

Any method or reference for ths type of problem ?

Comment: your first integral is not zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it converges, your first integral is $$\frac{a^{(c-1)/2} \Gamma((1-c)/2)}{2}$$
But the Gamma function has no zeros.

EDIT:  ... and I believe the second is $$\frac{\sqrt{2}\; \Gamma((1/4-c/2) \Gamma1/4+c/2)}{4\sqrt{\alpha}}$$ so again no zeros.

Comment: OK thanks ! It solves the problem of the first integral !